# ERROR: missing FROM- clause entry for table "Users"

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am using postgresql and pgadmin and I am new to this. I have a table "Users" that has the following columns `(Username, Name, Email, Phone, Discount, Password, token, serial, created_on, updated_on, points, reference)`.
I was trying to create a trigger for the table so that everytime a new insert occurs with an existing username in the reference field, the points of the used username will be incremented by 50. So there are two operations - updating the existing table, inserting the new values.

I tried creating a trigger function like this:

```
create or replace function points()
returns trigger as 
$BODY$
BEGIN
        if 
        new."Users"."reference" in (old."Users"."username")
        then
        Insert into "Users"(Username,Name,Email,Phone,Discount,Password,token,serial,created_on,updated_on,points,reference)
         values(new.Username,new.Name,new.Email,new.Phone,new.Discount,new.Password,new.token,new.serial,new.created_on,new.updated_on,new.points,new.reference);
        
        
         update "Users"
         set old."Users"."points" = old."Users"."points" + 50
         where "Users"."username" = (select "Users"."username" from "Users" where new."Users"."reference" in (old."Users"."username"));
                                     
                                     
         end if;
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

and a trigger like this:

```
create trigger referece_points
after insert 
on "Users"
for each row
execute procedure points();
```

But when I try to insert a new values in the "Users" table, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Users" LINE 1: SELECT new."Users"."reference" in (old."Users"."username") ^ Query: SELECT new."Users"."reference" in (old."Users"."username") CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function points() line 2 at IF
```

Answer (score 0):

New is composite variable of type that is related to table joined with trigger.

The code `new."Users"."reference"` has not any sense. You should to write just `new."reference"`.